# What is the "proper" form in which to write Java?

Tags: java, android, format

Personally, I write my Java like this:

```
class xyz {
    ...
}
```

OR

```
if (condition) {
    ...
}
```

etcetera...

In so many examples, I see code written like this:

```
class xyz 
{
    ...
}
```

OR

```
if (condition)
{
    ...
}
```

etcetera...

To me, my way makes the most sense because not only does it take less lines to write, but (again, in my opinion) looks more proper and professional. I'd love to know people's opinions - and reasoning behind them - as to which form is better and *why*.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/2715/45883

Comment: You should use the guidelines provided by the different languages. For instance C wants curly braces in a new line, Java wants them in the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one with opening braces on the same line is almost the standard Java programming guideline for years.
The original Sun Java guideline, that was never updated since 1999.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141270.html

Google Java guideline
https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.1-braces

Android style
https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

On the opposite side, many open source platforms like Apache/maven advocate brace in new line